# Bash: Check if enter was pressed

Tags: enter

How can I check in Bash if the **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** key has been pressed?
I'm using the read command:

```
read -p "Please press ENTER" var
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, check whether the exit status is normal (`$?` should be 0).

Secondly, check that `$var` equals `""`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check the length of the $var variable after it was set by the read call. If it's 0, the user just hit enter without typing anything else:

```
read -p "Please press ENTER" var
if [ ${#var} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Enter was hit"
fi
```

Comment: This if condition will probably also pass if the user pressed the space button, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
read var

echo $REPLY|hexdump -C
```