# Press any key to abort in 5 seconds

Tags: bash, user-input

Hi I'm trying to implement an event that will happen after a 5 second countdown, unless a key is pressed.  I have been using this code, but it fails if I press enter or space.  It fails in the sense that enter or space is detected as "".

```
echo "Phoning home..."
key=""
read -r -s -n 1 -t 5 -p "Press any key to abort in the next 5 seconds." key
echo
if [ "$key" = "" ]     # No Keypress detected, phone home.
     then python /home/myuser/bin/phonehome.py
     else echo "Aborting."
fi
```

After reading this post,
[Bash: Check if enter was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385782/bash-check-if-enter-was-pressed)

I gave up and posted here.  I feel like there must be a better way than what I have tried to implement.

Comment: what happens if you set a dummy value at the top for key, i.e. `key=nonesuch` ? Good luck.

Comment: That is a really good idea.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

The `read` manual says:

> The return code for `read` is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered
>   or read times out.

In your case, when the user hits any key within allowed time you wish to abort else continue.

```
#!/bin/bash
if read -r -s -n 1 -t 5 -p "TEST:" key #key in a sense has no use at all
then
    echo "aborted"
else
    echo "continued"
fi
```

**Reference:**
[Read Manual](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html)

**Note:**
The emphasis in the citation is mine.

Comment: This way seemed most elegant and this is the way I ended up doing this.  Thanks very much for the response.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385909/258523) in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10385782/258523) covers the "detecting `enter`" component of the question. You look at the exit code from `read`.

As to handling spaces there are two answers.

The problem with space is that under normal circumstances `read` trims leading and trailing whitespace from the input (and word-splits the input) when assigning the input to the given variables.

There are two ways to avoid that.

1. You can avoid using a custom named variable and use `$REPLY` instead. When assigning to `$REPLY` no whitespace trimming or word-splitting is performed. (Though looking for this just now I can't actually find this in the POSIX spec so this may be a non-standard and/or non-portable expansion of some sort.)
2. Explicitly set `IFS` to an empty string for the `read` command so it doesn't perform and whitespace trimming or word-splitting.

   ```
   $ IFS= read -r -s -n 1 -t 5 -p "Press any key to abort in the next 5 seconds." key; echo $?
   # Press <space>
   0
   $ declare -p key
   declare -- k=" "
   $ unset -v k
   $ IFS= read -r -s -n 1 -t 5 -p "Press any key to abort in the next 5 seconds." key; echo $?
   # Wait
   1
   $ declare -p key
   -bash: declare: k: not found
   ```